# What version of .NET Runtime will my code run on if server appears to have 4.5.1 and 4.6.1 installed?

Tags: .net

My code is targeting framework version 4.5.1.  According the the registry, this server is running .NET Framework 4.6.1 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) .  However, in the add/remove programs, I see that .NET Framework 4.5.1 is also installed.

So my question is- is my code running on 4.5.1 runtime or 4.6.1 runtime? I think that the answer is 4.6.1; I think that what appears in the add/remove programs is irrelevant, and only the registry key indicating 4.6.1 matters. But I would like confirmation, if anyone can provide it.

Comment: You should not see .NET Framework 4.5.1 in Programs. Make sure you read its name carefully, as SDK or Developer Pack is a different thing.

Comment: The framework is clearly remains 4.0. 4.5+ are just extensions. If you install 4.6+ runtime extensions, you should have no issues to run anything below. The numbers you see in VS are just your dev tools version.